# How to calculate sample population with species of known probability

Tags: probability, distributions, sample-size, negative-binomial-distribution, biostatistics

I have a sample of n=200,000 from 300 species. 8 species cover 80% of the samples. How can I calculate the right sample size such that each species has at least 1000 samples?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if the probabilities really are known, only the minimum probability really matters. So, lets reformulate to

- if probability of seeing A is $p$, how many samples should we take to have a high probability of seeing at least 1000 A's?

Then we can use the [negative binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution)
to find an answer. This is the distribution of the number of non-A's seen before we see A number 1000. You have 300 species, and the 8 most frequent ones have total probability $0.8$ . If the minimum probability is half of the mean probability for the 292 least frequent species, that is (using R)

```r
p <- (0.2/292)/2
        0.0003424658
```

We get

```r
qnbinom(c(0.05, 0.1, .2, .3, .4, 0.5, .6, .7, .8, .9, .95), 1000, p)
 [1] 2768844 2801339 2841057 2869894 2894711 2918027 2941475 2966700 2996403
[10] 3037924 3072499
```

so to have, say, at least 50% chance of seeing at least 1000 A's you need a total sample size of close to 3 million, much larger than your present sample size.